# Android with a Globally accessible class in all activities

Tags: global-variables, android

I am having some trouble with sharing a globalVaribale class:

here is my class:

```
public class GlobalObjects extends Application {

private Context context;

public GlobalObjects(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

// Variables

private Network network;


// Getters And Setters

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Network getNetwork() {
    return network;
}

public void setNetwork(Network network) {
    this.network = network;
}
}
```

and here is my android manifest file:

```
   <application
    android:name="GlobalObjects"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

I have added the global object to the already existing application tag. But when I run the class it gives errors:

```
08-07 21:19:58.867: E/AndroidRuntime(3588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 21:19:58.867: E/AndroidRuntime(3588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.electronicmenu.GlobalObjects: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.electronicmenu.GlobalObjects
```

Comment: Did you check to ensure the namespace is correct?

Comment: Should my global variable class be static? Or rather the variable static? Or is static not needed?